# Is Corine Land Cover 2018 available from WFS server?

Tags: wfs, raster-calculator, land-cover, server

I need to work with CLC 2018 across Europe from mobile devices with little storage capacity. It would be ideal if I could access it through a WFS server and extract just the areas and/or classes I need. I have found a few national websites with part of the dataset as WFS service but not the entire European dataset.

How can I do it?

Comment: https://image.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/rest/services/Corine/CLC2018_WM/MapServer

Comment: You may find that a WMS output is better for a mobile client with little storage capacity than a WFS.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I do it?

Copernicus don't offer a WFS for the data, they provide WMS and ArcGIS REST services.

See web services tab in their map viewer:

https://land.copernicus.eu/pan-european/corine-land-cover/clc2018?tab=mapview

They do also provide direct data download which includes vector:

https://land.copernicus.eu/pan-european/corine-land-cover/clc2018?tab=download

> The current CLC 2018 version is v.2020_20u1, which covers all EEA39 countries.

> Corine Land Cover products are available in both raster (100 resolution), and vector (ESRI and SQLite geodatabase). The Minimum Mapping Unit (MMU) for the CLC is 25 hectares for areal phenomena and 100 meter for linear phenomena. The time series (1990, 2000, 2006, 2012 and 2018) are complemented by change layers, which highlight changes in land cover with an MMU of 5 ha. If you are interested in changes between two surveys always use the CLC-Change layer, as this has a higher resolution than the status layer. Results can be filtered by using the search box.

So if you want WFS for your application, then you could download the vector data and create your own.

Comment: Thank you, I had figured that out already but was wondering if someone had already done a WFS for this data, since it has been around for some time now.